# How setting Camera2 API the standard camera?

Tags: android, android-camera2

If I use standard camera via Intent to capture image:

Open Camera:

```
 val takePicture = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (takePicture.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, TAKE_PICTURE)
        }
```

Camera Preview

[image: Camera Preview]

Result display on ImageView

[image: Result Image View]

If I use Camera2 API at: git: `https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic`
Result of Image not display portrait

Camera 2 Preview

[image: Camera2 Preview]

Result display on ImageView

[image: Image View]

My code display Image:

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.toString())
  imagePreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                        }
```

How setting Camera2 API to display result the same standard camera?

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question right.

Comment: if i use standard camera, preview and result is the same. but if i use camera 2 api to build my app. preview not the same result.

Comment: You need to adjust for hardware camera physical rotation, please post some code on how you're displaying that picture in a imageview / canvas.

Comment: Take a look at https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6

Comment: Do you use **android-Camera2Basic** via Intent, or you want to capture the picture without switching the activity?

Comment: @Alex, I want use Android-Camera2Basic to capture image, but result not the same standard camera.

Comment: @Megha Maniar: Android-Camera2Basic  had setting https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/kotlinApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.kt

Comment: Must i set ExifInterface to Image?

Answer (score 2):

In Camera2Basic example, the [ImageSaver](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/kotlinApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/ImageSaver.kt) does not rotate the captured JPEG with regards to device orientation. Instead, [Camera2BasicFragment.captureStillPicture()](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/59b9889259b31189469709216b6b1363e96281c2/kotlinApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.kt#L619) sets [CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#JPEG_ORIENTATION), which is only a *recommendation* for the camera firmware.

> Camera devices may either encode this value into the JPEG EXIF header, or rotate the image data to match this orientation. When the image data is rotated, the thumbnail data will also be rotated.

Most often, this recommendation 'only' sets the header, but some devices miss even that. See a recent [article](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6) on this feature and its reliability.

Please note that the EXIF orientation tag is not respected by all viewer software, therefore often the stock Camera applications do rotate the actual JPEG to default orientation.

Your code that loads the captured picture to **ImageView** currently ignores this tag. You can use [ExifInterface.getAttributeInt(TAG_ORIENTATION)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#getAttributeInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) to extract the orientation from the file or input stream. Or, if you capture an image and immediately display it, you can get device orientation directly from the sensor. Now it's time to decide if the camera stored the image as portrait (i.e. width is smaller than height), or as landscape, in which case it's your duty to rotate it for display. Don't rotate the bitmap according to this orientation. Instead, you can call **imagePreview**.[setImageMatrix()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix(android.graphics.Matrix)) to display the image correctly.

By the way, please don't decode the JPEG to full-scale bitmap in memory if you only need it to be passed to your **ImageView**: this may consume too much RAM. The easiest one-liner is to call [setImageURI()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I using Glide to display image to ImageView.  
Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load(File(file.toString())).into(imagePreview). But Xaomi Note 5: it display ok, But Sony xp: it rotation 90.  If I set orientation  to Sony XP, it will display ok, But Xaomi will not ok. Can you help this problem?

Comment: You cannot blindly set rotation for the ImageView. You could disable the code in `captureStillPicture()` to not set CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION. Then all devices will be on the same ground. Unfortunately, this means that in Portrait mode, all will store the picture incorrectly oriented. Or, you can check Jpeg parameters to understand whether the device actually rotated the Jpeg when it stored the file. If the width of the Jpeg is more than its height, and you expect a portrait image, then add rotation matrix.